# How to list products of a specific category in CMS block Magento 2 ???

Tags: content-management-system, magento2

I am new to magento2. I need to display specific category products in CMS block magento 2..

Please help me!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create phtml file and render it. 
Example:
{{block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" template="Magento_Catalog::description.phtml"}}